# Simple low pass filter in fixed point

Tags: arduino, embedded, fixed-point

I have a simple circuit setup to read the light level via an LDR into an Arduino. I'm trying to implement a simple low pass filter to data read in. How best to tackle this given that analogRead() returns an unsigned int.

I have tried to implement a simple fixed point representation but am unsure if this is the correct approach.

Here's a code snippet:

```
#define WLPF 0.1
#define FIXED_SHIFT 4

ldr_val = ((int)analogRead(A0)) << FIXED_SHIFT;
 while (true) {
    int newval = (int)analogRead(A0) << FIXED_SHIFT;
    ldr_val += WLPF*(newval - ldr_val);
    Serial.println(ldr_val >> FIXED_SHIFT, DEC);
}
```

Note the resolution of the ADC is 10 bits and I am working with an 8-bit Arduino Micro.

Comment: 10 bits shifted by 4 yields 14 bits, that's still positive.
Your low pass formula looks strange to me, though

Comment: I'm confident in the formula but not sure about my implementation of fixed point.

Comment: What's the ADC resolution? What values can `analogRead` return? If it returns an unsigned int, then why do you cast it to signed int? Overall, why do you use signed ints in an embedded system? That's just sloppy and bug-prone. Use the stdint.h types. If you shift data into the sign bits of a signed type, your program may halt and catch fire.

Comment: Also, using floating point arithmetic on a sluggish 8-bit MCU is just nonsense. It is not a PC. I doubt it even got a FPU. You either have no need for float numbers (most likely) or you picked the wrong MCU for the task.

Comment: @Lundin this is why I am looking for help on the implementation, I'm not sure of best practices for embedded systems. The ADC resolution is 10 bit and analogRead returns an unsigned int as is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: [There are many good answers to your question over at Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/fast-and-memory-efficient-moving-average-calculation).

Comment: WLPF is a double precision floating point value, so this implementation is far from "fixed point".  A correct filter will need accurate timing; here your timing is likely to be dominated by the time taken to execute `Serial.println()` which is likely to be variable - as will the performance of the filter therefore.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide any pointers on fixed point filters for embedded systems?

Comment: Note the timing and frequency response requirements for the desired filter are very loose, I'm just looking to slow down the analog input so it takes a second or two to reach its baseline

Comment: And again: Arduino is not C!

Comment: @Olaf I'm building my project using embedXcode where I am writing pure C code.

Comment: Isn't the arduino "language" essentially a library and some preprocessing in C++ anyway?

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz: Yes. But how is that related to the **different** language C?

Comment: It isn't but the filter implementation I am planning to write will be in pure C, hence the tag

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz: The code above clearly is not C! It apparently is Arduino, or at least uses an Arduino library. Whatever, it does not compile with a C compiler! So either you use C only (including C compiler, remove the Arduino tag and stick with AVR, or you do have to use C++ resp. Arduino.

Comment: Understood. thanks

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz : You can in many cases compile code written as C code using a C++ compiler; but it then becomes C++ code.  As it happens this code will not compile as C because the use of the Serial object makes it C++ only.

Comment: Okay, fully understood now!

Comment: To add to what @Clifford wrote: Even if you have code with identical syntax (thus it will compile as both languages), it may have different semantics (thus behave differently). There is enough to be found about the differences between C and C++. One simple example is the `const` qualifier. Others are more subtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a device with no FPU rather then multiplying by 0.1 (which in any case make this a floating not fixed point implementation) you should divide by 10:

```
#define WLPF_DIV 10

...

ldr_val += (newval - ldr_val) / WLPF_DIV;
```

However division on an 8 bit processor is often expensive (although probably dwarfed by the execution time of `Serial.println()` in the loop - but that is a different issue).  Instead it is more efficient to select a power of two so that the division can be performed with a right-shift.

```
#define WLPF_SHIFT 3  // divide by 8

...

ldr_val += (newval - ldr_val) >> WLPF_SHIFT ;
```

The use of signed `int` is problematic since right-shift of a signed type is undefined behaviour.  In this case this can be resolved by changing the code to:

```
#define WLPF_DIV 8

... 

ldr_val += (newval - ldr_val) / WLPF_DIV ;
```

The compiler will most likely spot the power-of-two constant and generate the code using an arithmetic-shift-right in any case.  However you would probably do better to reconsider the data type.

You still have a right-shift in the `Serial.println()` call, but that too could by replaced with a divide-by-16:

```
#define WLPF_DIV 8
#define FIXED_MUL  16

ldr_val = (int)analogRead(A0) * FIXED_MUL  ;

for(;;)
{
    int newval = (int)analogRead(A0) * FIXED_MUL ;
    ldr_val += (newval - ldr_val) / WLPF_DIV 
    Serial.println(ldr_val / FIXED_MUL, DEC);
}
```

Non-deterministic output of the data on a per sample basis is not going to make for a very accurate filter and will dominate the timing in any case so you have little control over the frequency response and it will not be stable. It also makes the previous performance optimisations rather pointless. You may want to think about that if it is important in your application - but that is a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. The requirements of the filter are very loose as I'm just looking to slow down a value so it takes 1-2 secs to reach baseline. However, I will perhaps look into using interrupts for a more precise timing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm paraphrasing from the book "Musical Applications of Microprocessors" by Hal Chamberlin, page 438:

If you allow large numbers in the accumulator, then you can make a first-order low-pass filter with one multiplication and some right-shifts.

```
  out = accum >> k
  accum = accum - out + in
```

Choose 'k' to change the cutoff frequency. The more shifts, the lower the low-pass cutoff, but the larger the value in the accumulator. With a 10-bit value from analog_read(), you can easily right-shift 4 places, and still have 2 bits of headroom in the accumulator (as @datafiddler noted above).

Cypress has some app-notes for their PSOC chips with similar equations, and using shifts. I remember one had a nice [table](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an2099-psoc-1-psoc-3-psoc-4-and-psoc-5lp-single-pole-infinite) that related number of shifts to the cutoff frequency. 
The approximate cutoff frequency is the sampling frequency divided by 2-pi times the gain factor:

> f0 ~ fs / (2 pi a)

where 'a' is that power of two.

Keep smoothin' those signals!

Answer (score 0):

Stick with integer arithmetics:

```
#define WLPF 9

filtered = ((long)filtered * WLPF + newValue) / (WLPF + 1);
```

Comment: in an 8 bit Arduino with 16 bit integer arithmetics, take care not to exceed the range (especially if you apply your FIXED_SHIFT) *** const unsigned long WLPF=9;

Comment: This code will perform really badly on AVR. No offence, but embedded software is a very specific field (at least what the questions asks for). If you are not experienced with it and know the architecture well, it is better not to answer.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, why would this code perform badly on an AVR?

Comment: Multiply by 0.1 is the same as divide by 10 so `0.1 * (newval - ldr_val)` is the same as `(newval - ldr_val) / 10` - your expression does not appear to be equivalent to the original code.  In any case division and to a lesser extent multiplication and the use of `long` will be relatively expensive on an 8 bit processor - though not as expensive as the floating point operation and it is all largely irrelevant given the `Serial.println()` call in the loop.

Comment: analogRead() is by far the slowest part, and, to really get a low pass filter, you need a defined cycle time (or take the actual cycle time into account)
So Olaf's proposal saves a few division cycles in favour of wait cycles.

If it would matter, Olaf were really so right.

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz: That's too broad. If you really need to optimise code, you first should know the underlying architecture very well. But I'm afraid, this also requires quite some practice. There is a reason school does not just take one year, but many of them.

Comment: @Olaf thanks, can you perhaps point me in the direction of an implementation that would perform well on AVR?

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz: Let apart such recommendations are off-topic here, I had to search for it, too. How about you find out yourself and - as you're at it - learn how to profile code to determine if it is **fast enough**? There is no to little use in over-optimising code, be it for speed or sizes.